# Implementing conditionals and loops in Tkinter GUI

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I need to add an `IF` statement, `FOR` and `WHILE` loop in my form, can someone add some kind of `IF` statment, `FOR` and `WHILE` loop in my code?

```
from tkinter import * # Ingress all components from Tkinter  
mGui = Tk()
mGui.geometry('400x400') # The size of the form window
mGui.title('Registration Form',)
def response():
    label3 = Label(text='Thank You!',fg='White', bg='Purple',font='none 16 bold').place(x=140,y=300) # The colours and font style and size used for the response
mlabel = Label(text='Registration Form',fg='White', bg='Purple',font='none 18 bold underline') # The colours and font style and size used for the form title
mlabel.pack()

mlabel2 = Label(text='Forename',fg='White', bg='Purple',font='times 14 bold').place(x=0,y=100) # The colours and font style and size used for the label

mlabel3 = Label(text='Surname',fg='White', bg='Purple',font='times 14 bold').place(x=0,y=150) # The colours and font style and size used for the label

mbutton = Button(text = 'Submit',command = response).place(x=150,y=250) #  Location of the the button 'submit' using the x and y axis

mGui.configure(background='Green') # Background colour of the form

mEntry = Entry(bg='White').place(x=100,y=100) 

mEntry = Entry(bg='White').place(x=100,y=150)

mGui.mainloop() # The code iterates
```

Comment: pretty much the person entering information into the form must put at least one character for the forename and surname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tkinter programs are *event-driven*, like all GUIs that I know of.

The only place where you can execute your own code is in *callbacks* or *timeouts*.

If you want to check the contents of the entry windows, you could do that in at least two ways:

1. Write a callback function for the `Submit` [button](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm) that retrieves the contents of the entry windows and validates them. You could e.g. use a messagebox telling the user that the entries are not valid.
2. You could also set up the entry windows to [validate](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/entry-validation.html) themselves when a key is pressed. I've used this to e.g. make the text or background of an entry window red if it contains invalid text. You could also put a tip in a `Label` below the entry windows, like "Both Forename and Surname must at least contain one character."

Comment: But my teacher asked for the whole class to add some level of if statement and while/for loop.

Comment: There should be at least some `if` statements in the callback. You can also use `while`-loops in callbacks, but you have to make sure they run fast, otherwise the GUI becomes unresponsive.